# R/Shiny - updateNumericInput - How to change the color of the label, and paste a variable

Tags: r, shiny, colors, tags, label

With *numericInpuT*, to modify the color of a label in UI, I can use *tags$span*, but I'm not sure how to use tags$span with *updateNumericInput* if, at the same time, I'm adding a variable.

In the example below (modified from *help("updateNumericInput")*), I can change the color and font size of the label in UI. But when I try to follow the same procedure with *updateNumericInput* I get, instead, an [object Object] in the label. Various attempts to get it right can be seen commented out in the text. Could it be that 'label' in *numericInput* and in *updateNumericInput* are treated differently?

The reason to modify the color on the server side is that I need to include, in the label, some variable that I'm calculating, in this case represented by Sys.time().

In the end, what I need is the bottom label to look like the 3rd label ("Input number 3 ..."), but in the selected color (#00ffff).

Thank you

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("controller", "Controller", 0, 20, 10),
  numericInput("inNumber", tags$span(style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12px;","Input number"), 0),
  numericInput("inNumber2", tags$span(style="color: #00ff00; font-size: 12px;","Input number 2"), 0),
  numericInput("inNumber3", tags$span(style="color: #0000ff; font-size: 12px;","Input number 3"), 0),
  numericInput("inNumber4", tags$span(style="color: #0000ff; font-size: 12px;","Input number 4"), 0)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$controller, {
    # We'll use the input$controller variable multiple times, so save it as x for convenience.
    x <- input$controller
    
    updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = x)
    
    updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber2",
                     # label = paste("Number label ", x),
                       value = x, min = x-10, max = x+10, step = 5)
    
    updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber3",
                       label = paste0("Input number 3 (b&w) on ",Sys.time()),
                       value = x, min = x-10, max = x+10, step = 5)
    
    # --- Here it comes - Build the string to be used by tags$span

    xx1    = 'style="color: #00ffff; font-size: 12px;"'
    xx2    = paste0("Input number 4 ", Sys.time())
    xx_all = paste0(xx1,",","\"",xx2,"\"")                    # "style=\"color: #00ffff; font-size: 12px;\",\"Input number 4 2022-10-19 15:37:44\""
    
    updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber4",
                     # label = tags$span(style="color: #00ffff; font-size: 12px;","Input number 4 (color)"),
                     # label = tags$span("style=\"color: #00ffff; font-size: 12px;\",\"Input number 4 (color) \", 2022-10-19 14:59:13 EDT"),
                     # label = HTML(as.character(tags$span(xx_all))),
                       label = tags$span(as.character(HTML(xx_all))),
                       value = x, min = x-10, max = x+10, step = 5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There is a similar concern with using html in update inputs on the rstudio shiny git hub: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3678

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `label` only accept character at this moment, `shiny.tag` can not be processed. However, we can write some JS to make the character become HTML node.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sliderInput("controller", "Controller", 0, 20, 10),
    numericInput("inNumber", tags$span(style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12px;","Input number"), 0),
    numericInput("inNumber2", tags$span(style="color: #00ff00; font-size: 12px;","Input number 2"), 0),
    numericInput("inNumber3", tags$span(style="color: #0000ff; font-size: 12px;","Input number 3"), 0),
    numericInput("inNumber4", tags$span(style="color: #0000ff; font-size: 12px;","Input number 4"), 0),
    tags$script(
        "
        $('#inNumber4').on('shiny:updateinput', function(e){
            setTimeout(function(){$('#inNumber4-label').html($('#inNumber4-label').text())}, 0.1);
        });
        "
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$controller, {
        x <- input$controller
        
        updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = x)
        
        updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber2",
                           value = x, min = x-10, max = x+10, step = 5)
        
        updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber3",
                           label = paste0("Input number 3 (b&w) on ",Sys.time()),
                           value = x, min = x-10, max = x+10, step = 5)
        
        updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber4",
                           label = tags$span(
                               style="color: #00ffff; font-size: 12px;", 
                               paste0("Input number 4 (color) ", Sys.time())) |> 
                                 as.character(),
                           value = x, min = x-10, max = x+10, step = 5)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. change the input to label `as.character`
2. add a listener to watch for the input update of `inNumber4`
3. When the event is triggered, the text is not updated immediately, we need to wait for a very tiny amount of time `setTimeout(..., 0.1)` before we can evaluate the text to become HTML

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I had to replace the "|>" characters by "%>%" and added "library(dplyr)" at the beginning of the code.

Comment: `|>` come with base R > 4.0. If you use the latest R version, there is no need to use  `dplyr`

Comment: Indeed. The pipe operator came in [version 4.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html).